# NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate's methods not being called in UISearchController's searchResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to migrate from `UISearchDisplayController` to `UISearchController`, but I'm having a difficult time getting `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`'s methods to be called in my `UISearchController`'s `searchResultsController`. `UISearchController` is instantiated as:

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.searchResultsViewController];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self.searchResultsViewController;
self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0); /* radr://17315477 */
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

The `searchResultsController` is a fairly boilerplate `UITableViewController` (`self.searchResultsViewController` from above). The `UITableViewDataSource` methods are all copied over from my old `UISearchDisplayController`. Things like:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
     return (self.searchFetchedResultsController.sections.count);
}
```

The `UITableViewController` is both a `UISearchResultsUpdating` and `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`. The delegate methods (that aren't getting called) are boilerplate from the docs. My `updateSearchResultsForSearchController:` is pretty basic as well:

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
     if (!searchController.isActive)
          return;

     self.searchFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
     self.searchFetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[cd] %@", @"name", searchController.searchBar.text];

     NSError *error = nil;
     if (![self.searchFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
          NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
     NSLog(@"%@", @([self.searchFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]));
}
```

I set the delegate every time right now because my problem is that the delegate methods do not get called after the `performFetch`. I'm really not sure what else to look at. I've confirmed in the debugger that the delegate is set both before and after and that it is set to the correct object. The `searchFetchedResultsController` lazy instantiation has not changed, and there is no cache to delete. When printing the fetchedObjets count, the count does update and is correct. If I throw a `[self.tableView reloadData]` after the `performFetch`, everything looks as it ought, but I know that's not a good idea. `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`'s methods just aren't getting called. Is anyone else seeing similar behavior or do I need to keep digging in my codebase? What are some things I could look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate thing to do here **is** to call the `UITableView`'s `reloadData` or to add/delete the changed rows after changing `fetchRequest.predicate`. I *knew* that `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`s are triggered on a change in the managed object **not** on a change in the predicate.

So why was I so sure that I was doing something wrong? Because it worked before, when I used a `UISearchDisplayController`, and now that I use `UISearchController`, it didn't work. What I failed to recall was that I was returning `YES` from `shouldReloadTableForSearchString:` which, of course, calls `reloadData`. It worked before, but not because of the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`.